# How can I combine these 2 worksheet_change events?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run multiple worksheet change events, but I don't know how to combine the two macros. Can anyone please show me how to combine them?
Macro 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 9 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then

      Else
      If newVal = "" Then

      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal

      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Macro 2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim rng As Range

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")

If Target.Row > 1 Then
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngDV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  str = Target.Validation.Formula1
  str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = ws.Range(str)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  If Application.WorksheetFunction _
    .CountIf(rng, Target.Value) Then
    Exit Sub
  Else
    i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Cells(i, rng.Column).Value = Target.Value
    rng.Sort Key1:=ws.Cells(1, rng.Column), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Create two sub and then call them both

Comment: Make them independent subs.  Then in your worksheet change sub, determine which condition trigger the change then call the appropriate sub(s).

Answer (score 0):

Both codes are merged under one Worksheet Change Event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range, oldVal As String, newVal As String

If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal

    If Target.Column = 9 Then
        If oldVal <> "" Then
            If newVal <> "" Then Target.Value = oldVal & ", " & newVal
        End If
    End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Second Code Added Here...
Dim ws As Worksheet, str As String, i As Integer, rngDV As Range, rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")

If Target.Row > 1 Then
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rngDV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    str = Target.Validation.Formula1
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)

    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = ws.Range(str)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Target.Value) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Cells(i, rng.Column).Value = Target.Value
        rng.Sort Key1:=ws.Cells(1, rng.Column), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks heaps everyone. I went with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Multiple Select

Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 2 _
        And Target.Row = 3 _
         Or Target.Row >= 9 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal

      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True


  ' Add to List data
On Error Resume Next
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Set ws = Worksheets("dynamicLists")

If Target.Row > 1 Then
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngDV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  str = Target.Validation.Formula1
  str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = ws.Range(str)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  If Application.WorksheetFunction _
    .CountIf(rng, Target.Value) Then
    Exit Sub
  Else
    i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Cells(i, rng.Column).Value = Target.Value
    rng.Sort Key1:=ws.Cells(1, rng.Column), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  End If

End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it this way.

```
Sub Macro1()
' your code here

Call Macro2
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
' your code here

End Sub
```